# Flutter - Update a Map from a Firebase Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I just started with Firebase, I have this map in my code:

```
Map Brain = {
  0: {
    0: '0-0',
    1: '0-1',
    2: '0-2',
    3: '0-3',
    4: '0-4',
  },
  1: {
    0: '1-0',
    1: '1-1',
    2: '1-2',
    3: '1-3',
    4: '1-4',
  },
};
```

And I created this Database on Firebase:

[image]

I would like to create a function that updates the map I have in my code with the one in the database on firebase.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: @MuhamadJalal Thank you for your answer, i have updated it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854828

Answer (score 0):

use `cloud_firestore` library https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

```
Future<void> setData(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  return await firestore
      .collection("botBrain")
      .doc("answers").set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i got this error: '''Error: The getter 'firestore' isn't defined for the class '_MyHomePageState'''' , do you know how can i solve it?

Comment: Init firebase project with flutter project have some details, please read the documentation or take a course about "Flutter-Firebase".