# Flutter - Update a Map from a Firestore Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I just started with firebase and I created this Database on Firestore:

[image]

I would like to create a function that, when the floatingactionbutton is pressed, it updates the map I have in my code with the one in the database on firebase.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:plus1/Brain.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  /// FIREBASE:
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbApp = Firebase.initializeApp();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fbApp,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print('Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(Brain.toString());
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

```
Map Brain = {
  0: {
    0: '0-0',
    1: '0-1',
    2: '0-2',
    3: '0-3',
    4: '0-4',
  },
  1: {
    0: '1-0',
    1: '1-1',
    2: '1-2',
    3: '1-3',
    4: '1-4',
  },
};
```

Hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Update a Map from a Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847164/flutter-update-a-map-from-a-firebase-database)

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the data and then process it. An example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data):

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('posts/$postId/starCount');
starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value;
    updateStarCount(data);
});
```

You can do an asynchronous call when the button is pressed and then update your UI, e.g. with setState().